# How to pass ControllerBase as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a asp.net mvc 4 project where I have many lines of dublicated code. After some thinking I decide to refactor it. I lift out of context some code where have the ViewBags. And sending to this method ControllerBase as parameter, but dont know how to pass it as parameter inside my controller. Anybody help me?

```
public static void ReturnViewBag(ControllerBase target, string query)
    {
        var model = new Repository<Table>().GetRow(name);
        if (model != null) {
                target.ViewBag.SomeName = model.SomeColumn;
        }
    }

public ActionResult Index() {
    this._someHelper.ReturnViewBag(/*here is some var which i dont know*/, someQuery);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You are creating a special method just to return the `ViewBag`? Why?

Comment: Just add inside: this.

Comment: because i use the same code in other actionresults

Comment: @JernejNovak where inside?

Comment: this._someHelper.ReturnViewBag(this, someQuery);

Comment: Why would you move that method out into it's own class when you should just be putting in your own vase class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass current controller instance use "this" keyword like below:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    this._someHelper.ReturnViewBag(this, someQuery);
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `ControllerBase` of the current controller you are working in you can use:
`this.ControllerContext.Controller`.